# How to add an existing function to new createElement elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to give `newButton` the `colourChange` function.
I think I need to use `DOMNodeInserted` but I'm not quite sure how.

```
let button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const colours = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'];
const colourChange = button.forEach(press => {
    press.style.backgroundColor = colours[0];
    press.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = colours[(colours.indexOf(e.target.style.backgroundColor) + 1) % colours.length];
    });
});

const createButton = document.getElementById('new button');
createButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('creating')
    const newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newButton.innerHTML = "click";
    newButton.classList.add('button');
    document.body.appendChild(newButton);
})
```

Comment: `colorChange` is not a function, it's `undefined`...

Comment: I'm still trying to get to grips with functions. Should I remove 'const colourChange ='?

Answer (score 0):

Edit to the following

```
colourChange();
function colourChange(){ 
let button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const colours = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'];
button.forEach(press => {
press.style.backgroundColor = colours[0];
press.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 
colours[(colours.indexOf(e.target.style.backgroundColor) + 1) % colours.length];
});
});
}
const createButton = document.getElementById('new button');
createButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
console.log('creating')
const newButton = document.createElement("button");
newButton.innerHTML = "click";
newButton.classList.add('button');
document.body.appendChild(newButton);
colourChange();
})
```

Comment: bug 1: clicking new button sets all buttons back to red

Comment: bug 2: the new buttons have a weird sequence going on, buttons are going red - green- red -  green. or they don't cycle.